# Create iOS class inheritance

Tags: ios

I have a problem. I'm a beginning iOS programmer.

I have created a web service in that I can access from my app.

In my C# code I have a parent custom class (DataDocument) with an Id (int), Name (string) and a list of Records (DataObject). 
DataObject his yet another custom class, DataObject has again a Name (string), Type (string) and Value (object).

Is it possible to setup the same structure in iOS so it would be easy to process my data?
My C# Class:

```
public class DataDocument
{
    public Int32 Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<DataObject> Records { get; set; }
}

public class DataObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my DataDocument.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "DataObject.h"

@interface DataDocument : NSObject
{
    NSInteger * DataDocumentId;
    NSString * DataDocumentName;
    DataObject * DataDocumentRecords;
}


@property(strong, nonatomic) NSInteger * DataDocumentId;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString * DataDocumentName;
@property DataObject * DataDocumentRecords;
@end
```

And my DataObject.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "DataDocument.h"

@interface DataObject: DataDocument
{
    NSString *DataObjectName;
    NSString *DataObjectType;
    NSObject *DataObjectValue;
}

@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString * DataObjectName;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString * DataObjectType;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSObject * DataObjectValue;
@end
```

Comment: Rather than asking it on SO, you should start reading the basic Objective-C tutorials first.

Comment: Different programming languages usually don't have compatible types. There is no equivalent for `List<>` in Objective-C. Then there is the slight issue of everything else being different as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your DataObject.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DataObject : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *type;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id value;
@end
```

Your DataDocument.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DataDocument : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger uniqueId;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString          *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray    *dataObjectArray;
@end
```

But Yeah, "you should start reading the basic Objective-C tutorials first"

Comment: I have done research, but without success. I will do more research in future before I ask questions. I also have studied some basic object-c, but maybe I just want to fast. Thanks you for your answer